# Pythonic way to conditionally iterate over items in a list

Tags: python, lxml

New to programming in general, so I'm probably going about this the wrong way. I'm writing an lxml parser where I want to omit HTML table rows that have no content from the parser output. This is what I've got:

```
for row in doc.cssselect('tr'):
    for cell in row.cssselect('td'):
        sys.stdout.write(cell.text_content() + '\t')
    sys.stdout.write '\n'
```

The `write()` stuff is temporary. What I want is for the loop to only return rows where `tr.text_content != ''`. So I guess I'm asking how to write what my brain thinks should be 'for a in b if a != x' but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Umm, what exactly are you trying to do? Parsing xml is not simple at all. Maybe you should try something else since you're just beginning? How about you show us some sample input/output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for row in doc.cssselect('tr'):
    cells = [ cell.text_content() for cell in row.cssselect('td') ]
    if any(cells):
        sys.stdout.write('\t'.join(cells) + '\n')
```

prints the line only if there is at least one cell with text content.

Comment: Only problem is that it doesn't align things properly since it drops all empty cells. So one row could have 1 non-empty cell and another 2 non-empty cell and the would have a non tabular alignment.

Comment: @troutinator - I have edited the answer, now it prints all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**ReEdit**:

You know, I really don't like my answer at all.  I voted up the other answer but I liked his original answer because not only was it clean but self explanatory without getting "fancy" which is what I fell victim to:

```
for row in doc.cssselect('tr'):
    for cell in row.cssselect('td'):
        if(cel.text_content() != ''):
            #do stuff here
```

there's not much more of an elegant solution.

**Original-ish**:

You can transform the second `for` loop as follows:

```
[cell for cell in row.cssselect if cell.text_content() != '']
```

and turn it into a list-comprehension.  That way you've got a prescreened list.  You can take that even farther by looking at the following example:

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]
newList = [y for x in a for y in x]
```

which transforms it into `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`.  Then you can add in the `if` statement at the end to screen out values.  Hence, you'd reduce that into a single line.

Then again, if you were to look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
ifilter(lambda x: x.text_content() != '', row.cssselect('td'))
```

produces an iterator which you can iterate over, skipping all items you don't want.

**Edit**:

And before I get more downvotes, if you're using python 3.0, `filter` works the same way.  No need to import `ifilter`.

Comment: This is the problem I ran into. Slightly rephrased question to clarify.

Comment: Wowsers, gimme a second to edit my post!  Glad people are so quick to the draw.

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need.